# how can I show the elapsed time in hh:mm:ss:SSS format in C

Tags: c, time-format

I will do some process.
Then I want to show this processing time in `hh:mm:ss:SSS` format in C.
If anyone know, could you explain me?
I am writing the c code in visual studio 2008.
Thanks in advance.

For eg.
Start time.
Do some process.
End time.
Elapsed time = end time - start time.
Then i want to show this elapsed time in `hh:mm:ss:SSS` format.

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/difftime/ and http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Time_t&oldid=450752800

Answer (score 0):

```
time_t t = time( 0 ); 
char tmp[64]; 
strftime( tmp, sizeof(tmp), "%H:%M:%S", localtime(&t) );
```

I do not know how to get the SSS so I hope this will give you some advice.